# How to open an Angular app other than localhost?

Tags: angular

I want to open my angular app other than localhost for my development purpose but running into below error, any guidance on how to fix it?

```
username$ ng serve --open --host=ibaitdev.company.com
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ibatdev.company.com
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ibatdev.company.com
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
```

I changed my `/etc/hosts` as below

```
#
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       ibaitdev.company.com
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             ibaitdev.company.com
```

Comment: You can use any of those in your browser but you still need to append the correct port it is being served on in the browser URL

Comment: ibatdev is not ibaitdev. Spelling matters.

Comment: @Igor - but its throwing an error right?how do I use them in the browser URL?are you saying to add the port numbers in /etc/hosts ?

Comment: --host 0.0.0.0 could help?

Comment: `--host 0.0.0.0` still opens on `http://localhost:4200`

Comment: You now changed the spelling in your question, but did you run `ng serve` with the correct hostname? The error output still shows `ibatdev`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check` will allow you to connect to the server using your IP 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost.

This will disable host check and allow to access from outside with IP address instead of localhost.

In newer versions of the AngularCLI (higher than v5), you can use 0.0.0.0 as the IP again to host it on your network.

Answer (score 3):

You can do ng serve --host=*127.0.0.1*
and then when you go to your browser just go to that domain name. (127.0.0.1:4200)